Virtual enviroment - Why can't I set enviromental variable?
I am trying to start up daphne for my Django project. The issue is that I am not able to set up the envirometnal variable for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
I am using python venv.
Path of my project is as follows:
C:\Users\HP ELITEBOOK\Documents\Projects\myenv\MyProject\MyProject\settings
I tried many different combinations already.
I activate venv.
I cd into "C:\Users\HP ELITEBOOK\Documents\Projects\myenv\MyProject" and use command:
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyProject.settings

But when I try to check the variable with echo I still get only "%DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%". Which to my understanding means the variable is not set.
EDIT
These are my cmd prompt inputs:
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyProject.settings
echo %DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%

output is:
%DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%

Not exactly sure if the echo does what I think it will but the main point is that I keep getting the same error when starting daphne.
"Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."

How exactly are you echoing it? Please just show a command line session, with the exact commands typed and their output, without embellishing explanation or interpretation.

You can now see it in the edited version. Thank you.

What shell are you using? Looks to me like it's simply not interpreting %...% as a variable notation, but I don't know too much about Windows shells…

This is powershell through VS code.

@JohnnyHavlis the way to read / write environment variables in powershell is different from that of Command Prompt. See the duplicates.
